# Taylor Series Error Bounds of sin

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to estimate the error in approximating of $\sin(x) \approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ while $|x| \le \frac{1}{2}$.

I assume that the error is somewhere between $x_0$ and $x$.

Since this is a 4th order approximation, then $(sin(x))''''$ = $sin(x)$, so $x_0 = 0$.

the error is supposed to be in the range of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

lets sign the error as $c$, then
$$\biggl|\frac{\sin(c)}{4!}x^4\biggr|$$
as I know, now i'm supposed to select c as the smallest value of $0$ as $c$ and $x$ as $\frac{1}{2}$ but then i get the result of $0$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Since $x - \frac{x^3}6$ includes the fourth-degree term (it is $0$), you can use the fifth degree term for error estimation.

Comment: @Arthur so the solution whenever I get zero as the result of $Rn(x)$ is to use next order in series?

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that you get zero as a result for an _actual term in the Taylor series_, not for the error term, then you may as well say that you include it. As for how to calculate the error term, I suggest you take a look at the original theorem again and try to find the exact expression for the error term. Once you've done that, find the smallest number you can safely say is larger than that error term, given what you know about $x$ and $c$ and the sine function. That's the answer you're looking for.